# interpretation of parentheses in ToExpression

Tags: plotting

The code below generates the plot "z" and gives a name to the "Show" function.

```
paraName = firstProject;
z = ListPlot[{{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}];
fontSize = 12;
ToExpression[
 ToString[paraName] <> 
  "Pack=Show[z,Frame\[Rule]True,Axes\[Rule]False,LabelStyle\[Rule]{\
FontFamily\[Rule]Arial,FontSize\[Rule]14},FrameLabel\[Rule]{xAxis \
(mm)," <> ToString[paraName ] <> "(hr)}]"]
```

In x and y-axis labels, it seems that ToExpression does not interpret properly the parenthesis. Instead of showing : "xAxis (mm)" or "firstProject (hr)", the parenthesis are skipped: "mm xAxis" and "firstProject hr". It looks like ToExpression interprets  "xAxis (mm)" for example as the product of xAxis and mm.

Comment: your label strings need to be quoted with escaped quotes, `\"xaxis (mm)\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just confirming what i said in comment, this works:

```
 paraName = firstProject;
 z = ListPlot[{{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}];
 fontSize = 12;
 ToExpression[
  ToString[paraName] <> "Pack=Show[z,Frame\[Rule]True,Axes\[Rule]False,
   LabelStyle\[Rule]{FontFamily\[Rule]Arial,FontSize\[Rule]14},
   FrameLabel\[Rule]{\"xAxis (mm)\",\"" <> ToString[paraName] <> "(hr)\"}]"]
                     ^^          ^^ ^^                                ^^
```

In your origial incarnation `xaxis (mm)` is not a string (within the string) so `ToExpression` treats it as the multiplication of the symbols `xAxis` and `mm`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take an easier approach without `ToExpression`?

```
paraName = "firstProject";
ListPlot[{{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}},
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"xAxis (mm)", paraName <> " (hr)"},
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 14}]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

Since the OP insists in a comment that he must use `Show`, I suggest it might be done this way, which is not all that different the my first attempt.

```
paraName = "firstProject";
z = ListPlot[{{0, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}];
myPlot[plot_, name_] := 
 Show[plot, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"xAxis (mm)", name <> " (hr)"}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 14}]
pack = myPlot[z, paraName]
```

[image: show]

Comment: I need to give the name Show[

Comment: Without getting into too much details, I need to give the value of paraName to Show[z,....], i.e firstProject=Show[z...]. All the code is actually in a For loop, and at each iteration the value of paraName changes, and the content of the list to plot also. Once out of the loop, all the graphs are shown in an 2D grid using GraphicsGrid.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly.